# How to navigate google maps app from flutter app

Tags: google-maps, flutter

I want to access google maps app when I tap a button with lat / long in flutter app. I figured that `google_maps_flutter` plugin already have it out of the box, eg [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NX3F.jpg). I want to do the same using a custom button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to open goold maps and other maps on users device, you can use [map_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/map_launcher). Here is an example of how to use it:

```
import 'package:map_launcher/map_launcher.dart';

if (await MapLauncher.isMapAvailable(MapType.google)) {
  await MapLauncher.launchMap(
  mapType: MapType.google,
  coords: coords,
  title: title,
  description: description,
 );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm thinking since `google_maps_flutter ` has the feature already, is there no way I can use that instead. The `google_maps_flutter` version is more efficient

Comment: google_maps_flutter has some problems with ios map I think.